# Google Maps Javascript API - Getting coordinates from Address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have problems in using the Google Maps Javascript API to retrieve the coordinates based on the address. I searched through Google forum and found that Geocoding concept has resolved this issue.

But my application does not support Geocoding. Is it not possible to implement this logic using Javascript API

Comment: "But my application does not support Geocoding" why not? Show your code, who does not support the geolocation is the browser.

Answer (score 4):

Example from Google API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=fr :

```
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }

<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
  <div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
    <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </div>
</body>
```